# How can I bypass the error message "a newer version is installed" and install IE10?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, windows-update, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

In the last month, the Windows update tried to update daily to IE10 and always failed. The error code I got was always ("9C48"). (I have Windows 7, 64-bit version)

I tried to remove IE9 and install IE10 manually, but I got the error "a newer version is installed".

Thus currently I have neither IE9 or IE10.

So I am stuck and happy with Firefox. I am only interested in IE in case some website (such as government websites) does not work in FF, and then I am not able to submit my tax income or so.

Does anyone know how to overcome this and get IE back?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem occurs because of a bad copy of Internet Explorer 9. Try [the suggestion from this forum thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/bd28f518-4a67-436f-92cc-1b2499c7a707/) and let me know if it worked:

> - Uninstall IE9, if you already have it installed, and restart the    computer.
> - Download the installer.
> - Disconnect from the internet. **This is important** because the installer    attempts to download the latest, bad binaries from
>     Windows Update.
> - Let the install finish, and restart.
> - Reconnect to the internet and check Windows Update. If all went well,    you should be able to see the Cumulative Update for IE9,
>     instead of    IE9 itself.

Again, the key is to install without any internet connection, to prevent the installer from fetching the latest and bad binaries.

[Manually install IE10](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie-10/worldwide-languages) 
[Reset Windows Update components](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058)

Comment: It would be nice if you post link to original source http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/bd28f518-4a67-436f-92cc-1b2499c7a707/ when you do copy/paste from other forum.

Comment: This actually did the trick, I had to uninstall all versions of IE and then clean the registry manually.
Then I had to reboot, and start installing IE from scratch. Then it all worked fine. I guess something with either installation ou registry keys got messed up during the windows update. The trick is to completely remove IE and then start again.